# How to justify this limit (linked to gamma function)?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

We know this expression

$\int_0^{\sqrt[3]{n}} t^{x-1}e^{-t} \left[ 1 - \exp \left (-n \int_0^{\frac t n}\left(\frac t n - \sigma\right) \frac 1 {(1- \sigma)^2}d \sigma\right)\right]dt$

we also know that

$\sup_{t\in[0,{\sqrt[3]n}]}\left[ 1 - \exp \left (-n \int_0^{\frac t n}\left(\frac t n - \sigma\right) \frac 1 {(1- \sigma)^2}d \sigma\right)\right] \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$.

How to prove

$\int_0^{\sqrt[3]{n}} t^{x-1}e^{-t} \left[ 1 - \exp \left (-n \int_0^{\frac t n}\left(\frac t n - \sigma\right) \frac 1 {(1- \sigma)^2}d \sigma\right)\right]dt \to 0 $ when $n \to \infty$

And

$\int_{n}^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t} \left[ 1 - \exp \left (-n \int_0^{\frac t n}\left(\frac t n - \sigma\right) \frac 1 {(1- \sigma)^2}d \sigma\right)\right]dt \to 0 $ when $n \to \infty$

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n(t):= \left[ 1 - \exp \left (-n \int_0^{\frac t n}\left(\frac t n - \sigma\right) \frac 1 {(1- \sigma)^2}d \sigma\right)\right]$

$|\int_0^{\sqrt[3]{n}} t^{x-1}e^{-t} \left[ 1 - \exp \left (-n \int_0^{\frac t n}\left(\frac t n - \sigma\right) \frac 1 {(1- \sigma)^2}d \sigma\right)\right]dt | \leq \sup_{t \in[0,n^{\frac{1}{3}}]}|f_n(t)||\Gamma(x)| \to 0 $ when $n \to \infty$

For the second expression, 
$|\int_n^{\infty} t^{x-1}e^{-t}f_n(t)dt| \leq \int_n^{\infty} t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt \to 0$ since $f_n(t)$ increases monotonically with $t$ to $1$ on this interval.